# Perform Update Of Latest (Min) And Get Back Key

Tags: t-sql, min

Have a very active table with PK Int Iden

What I need is:

```
update table 
set statusID = 7, folderID = 12 
where PK = ( select MIN(PK) from tbl where statusID = 5)
```

What I want need back is PK value or if there is no status = 5 then some indicator it failed.

Comment: What database system (name and version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's SQL Server 2005+, you can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to return the PK of the updated row:

```
update table 
set statusID = 7, folderID = 12 
output inserted.PK
where PK = ( select MIN(PK) from tbl where statusID = 5)
```

The above statement will (attempt to) update the row with the PK returned from the subquery *and* return a rowset with a single column, `PK`. The returned rowset will contain the updated row's PK, or nothing if nothing was updated.